# Did eve say "I have created a man just as the LORD did!"?

Tags: genesis, translation-philosophy

Edit: Answers are being given here: [Did eve say “I have created a man just as the LORD did!”?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19019/did-eve-say-i-have-created-a-man-just-as-the-lord-did)

---

NET Version:  "I have created a man just as the LORD did!" (Genesis 4:1)

Most other translations have her *giving credit* to the Lord, whereas this one has her pretending to be a Godess.

While this translation at first surprised me, it seems consistent in it's own way to Eve's original desire to be a God, whereas the other versions seem to have her hoping in God.

The variation seems diametrically opposed to the traditional thought "The Lord has helped me"

Is there a biblical or translational reason to think this might be accurate?